# JavaScript: Inherit static object like static primitive

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, oop, inheritance

I have the following Code:

```
class Base {
 static id = 5;
 static arr = [];
}

class A extends Base {}
class B extends Base {}
```

This gives every sub-class its own static id property:

```
A.id++;

console.log(A.id) : 6  (Only this one got increased)
console.log(B.id) : 5
console.log(Base.id) : 5
```

However this is not the case for Objects.
When the Subclass gets created, a reference to Base-Class's Object is passed, instead of (in the case of Primitives) a simple copy. This gives the following result:

```
A.arr.push('a');

console.log(A.arr) : ['a']
console.log(B.arr) : ['a']     (I want this to stay empty)
console.log(Base.arr) : ['a']  (I want this to stay empty)
```

How would I have to change `static arr = [];` so that each sub-class gets its own static array?

Comment: Just put `static arr = [];` in `class A` and `class B` as well.

Comment: What are you using `arr` and `id` for? This smells like a design issue. What do your subclasses represent?

Comment: @Bergi The above is just a small-scale example. 
Doing that for every single class in a real project is a lot of redundant duplicate code.

Comment: Exactly that's why I said it's a design issue. Why would every single class in your project need its own array?

Comment: @Bergi
My Base Class in reality is 'Game', which has multiple subclasses (types of games), which furthermore have multiple Subclasses being the individual games.
Example: Game -> TwoPlayerRoundBasedGame -> TicTacToe.
Now for each Game, I want to have a List of Running Instances. I want to save it in a static Array of the game's class. TicTacToe.games = []. Doing this for every game is redundant, so I'd like to do it by inheritance, just like with the id.

Comment: "*I want to have a List of Running Instances*" - well, you shouldn't store these in static properties of the respective class. What if you want to have a separate list of "running" instances for some other purpose (testing, representing remote games, etc)? Store these in your application, not on your class; that way you can create multiple applications from the same code.

Comment: Also notice that `Game.arr` *should* contain all running `Game` instances, no matter what subclass they have. If you want a separate list that contains only TicTacToe games, make a separate list. It's not the responsibility of the `Game` class to do that.

Comment: And last but not least, reconsider whether an inheritance hierarchy `Game -> TwoPlayerRoundBasedGame -> TicTacToe` is really the best design. Maybe they should be mere interfaces? Maybe they should be mixins? Maybe you should use composition instead?

Comment: Absolutely agreed with all of @Bergi's points. I answered the literal question, but rethinking the design is almost certainly a better idea, especially now knowing the use case.

Comment: @Bergi Pretty sure JavaScipt doesn't have interfaces. And yes, I know that `Game.arr` contains all instances (and that I could simply name-check the constructor of the instances to get an array for a specific game).
But I agree with your points and will restructure my Code. Thank you.

Comment: @FireFuro99 Yes, there's no JS object for an interface, but you can (and should) still design your code with interfaces (type signatures) in mind. Remember that (class) inheritance is not the only way to share code between multiple objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A.arr` is as distinct from `B.arr` as `A.id` is from `B.id`. The issue is that `A.id++` is equivalent to `A.id = A.id + 1`, which replaces the value of `A.id` with a new value. `A.arr.push('a')` does not replace the contents of `A.arr`, which is a reference to the same object in `B.arr`.

This has nothing to do with classes or static members. Observe:

```js
let a = [];
let b = a;
a.push(1);
console.log('a refers to the same object as b; change that object, both a and b change');
console.log(`a=${a}; b=${b}`);
b = [...a, 2];
console.log('b refers to a different object from a');
console.log(`a=${a}; b=${b}`);
```

I assume you are asking how to assign a new object to every subclass. Since AFAIK JavaScript doesn't have subclass hooks, I believe the only way would be to do it manually for each subclass.

```js
class Base {
  static arr = [];
}

class A extends Base {
  static arr = [];
}
class B extends Base {
  static arr = [];
}

A.arr.push(1);
B.arr.push(2);
console.log(`A.arr=${A.arr}; B.arr=${B.arr}`);
```

Another approach is to use a static getter to do it for you. For example, this might work:

```js
class Base {
  static _arr = null;
  static get arr() {
    return (this._arr ??= []);
  }
}

class A extends Base {}
class B extends Base {}

A.arr.push(1);
A.arr.push('a');
B.arr.push(2);
B.arr.push('b');
console.log(`A.arr=${A.arr}; B.arr=${B.arr}`);
```

Comment: _“`A.arr` is as distinct from `B.arr`”_ — `A.arr === B.arr`; they’re identical. Saying that they’re distinct is misleading.

Comment: @SebastianSimon It's "*as distinct as*", a comparison. Notice that also `A.id === B.id`. Yes, they're identical.

Comment: Thank you!
I also had the idea of using static getters, but static get arr() {return []}; didn't work. But yours works perfectly, thank you!